# Action method is been called directly as soon as application starts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stack-trace

I have an MVC Module. It is surprisingly redirecting to  an `AccessDenied` action method as soon as application start. I tried putting logs to see which action method or which part of app is calling this access method so that it comes to hit this method as soon as app starts.

So I tried putting `Environment.StackTrace` in log but I am not able to get anything from log. My code is something like this

```
public ActionResult AccessDenied(string errorMessage)
    {
        logger.Debug("Calling Access Denied from Base Controller \n Stacktrace is : \n" + Environment.StackTrace);
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        return View("AccessDenied");
    }
```

And the log by this method is

```
{DEBUG}10/15 14:46:16 - Calling Access Denied from Base Controller 
 Stacktrace is : 
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at CMP.CBS.Websites.Receivable.Controllers.BaseController.AccessDenied(String errorMessage) in E:\Projects\CDP-AR\SourceCode\CDP-AR\CMP.CBS.Websites.Encounter\CMP.CBS.Websites.Receivable\Controllers\BaseController.cs:line 261
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ResumeStepsFromThreadPoolThread(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpAsyncResult.Complete(Boolean synchronous, Object result, Exception error, RequestNotificationStatus status)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.PollLockedSessionCallback(Object state)
   at System.Threading._TimerCallback.TimerCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading._TimerCallback.PerformTimerCallback(Object state)
```

and content of my RouteConfig is

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "CMP.CBS.Websites.Receivable.Login" }
            );

           //routes.MapRoute(
           // "Default",
           //"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           //new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           //new[] { "CMP.CBS.Websites.Receivable.Login" }
           //);

            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "ARListing",
              url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "ARListing", action = "ARListing", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

> I tried find usages of this action method by ReSharper as well and there is no such direct call  for this action method. It has 3-4 references and all are from another action methods. But StackTrace don't have any such traces.
>
> **PS:** This behavior is only on live/test server as on local I do not have that another module which interacts with it.

**Edit :** Adding more information of controllers and project setup as asked by Jenny O'Reilly -

There is one MVC app module on client side (test/live server) which trying to interact with my new MVC module and I do not have access to that. When user first time clicks on the link to my module, it redirects to access denied. PS: it happens only first time.

I have logger in Global.asax which adds its log
Gobal.asax File looks like -

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            // Initialize log4net
            log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("ApplicationStart");
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            logger.Debug("[CMP] Application Start ");

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

User is expected to access `ARListing` page which has `Url.AbsolutePath`(Means action method and controller) like `/Receivable/ARListing/ARListing` from another module.

My ARListingController loos like

```
[CheckLoggedIn]
[AllowedToSeeThePage]
public class ARListingController : BaseController
{
  public ActionResult ARListing(string patient)
    {
       // Some Code to calculation, long enough to post here
    }
 }
```

There is `BaseController` file which has constructor and one `AccessDenied` action method.

```
   public class BaseController : CMPControllerBase
    {
        public BaseController()
        {
          // Some Calculation and setting up some flags
          // No redirection code
        }
       public ActionResult AccessDenied(string errorMessage)
        {
            logger.Debug("Calling Access Denied from Base Controller \n Stacktrace is : \n" + Environment.StackTrace);
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            return View("AccessDenied");
        }
    }
```

Inside CMPControllerBase there is also a constructor but no redirection code.

I do not have any redirection to AccessDenied from CheckLoggedIn.
But in AllowedToSeeThePage I am redirecting to access denied and code of this file looks like -

```
public class AllowedToSeeThePageAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
          logger.Debug("Custom Filter: Executing CustomAttr's OnActionExecuting");
          if (baseController != null && !baseController.IsAllowedToSeeThisPage && !filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
            {
                logger.Debug("IsAllowedtoSeeThis Page : " + baseController.IsAllowedToSeeThisPage.ToString());
                logger.Debug("Custom Filter: trying to redirect to AccessDenied");

                string errorMessage = "";
                if (!baseController.HasValidRecordForPatient)
                {
                    errorMessage = "No record of PatInformation entry found for this patient";
                }
                else if (!baseController.IsAllowedToSeeThisPage)
                {
                    errorMessage = "You do not have valid counties to see this patient details";
                }
                string url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext).Action("AccessDenied", "Base", new { errorMessage });
                filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
                logger.Debug("Custom Filter: Redirected to AccessDenied" + errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

and logs looks like -

```
{DEBUG}10/15 14:46:08 - [CMP] Application Start 
{DEBUG}10/15 14:46:15 - Called BaseController from : /Receivable/Base/AccessDenied
{DEBUG}10/15 14:46:16 - Calling Access Denied from Base Controller 
 Stacktrace is : 
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at CMP.CBS.Websites.Receivable.Controllers.BaseController.AccessDenied(String errorMessage) in E:\Projects\CDP-AR\SourceCode\CDP-AR\CMP.CBS.Websites.Encounter\CMP.CBS.Websites.Receivable\Controllers\BaseController.cs:line 261
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
    .. goes on as above stacktrace mentioned
```

Please suggest me that why this action method is being invoked.

Comment: can you pass the content of Route.Config  file?

Comment: Have you applied any custom attribute/action filter?

Comment: @RezaAghaei , Yes I have added action filter also but there are also logs in that filter and I guess stacktrace should able to trace the ActionFilter . Please correct if I am wrong

Comment: You seem to have two MapRoutes with the same URL scheme. I gues this is an error. Also: Via which URL are you accessing your site? Have you tried Fiddler or FireBug to see what the server is returning (eg. Redirect)?

Comment: If you are debugging the website, do yo have access to the start url in project properties? If not, you'll get described behaviour

Comment: @jgauffin , I am not able to get you by " If you are debugging the website," . Are you talking about start url of project properties, that field is blank with specific page value Login/Login. Please suggest.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly , You are right. I will remove second one but do you think it may cause a redirect to a particular action method?

Comment: I don't think that defining an URL scheme twice will lead to calling a particular action method. How does the URL look like that you are requesting via the browser?

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly , I don't know the base URL but the Url.AbsolutePath should be /Receivable/ARListing/ARListing

Comment: Do you have any method that is executed before the actions (like OnActionExecuting)? It could be that inside that method is some kind of permission checking that fails.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly, I have the constructor of this controller which is called before the OnACtionExcecuting . But in that constructor I am not redirecting anywhere and surprising is that constructor is called just because of this action method. I added logs in BaseController constructor to see who is calling this constructor then it logs -  "Called BaseController from : /Receivable/Base/AccessDenied"

Comment: @jgauffin, If I don't have access to start url then shouldn't it throw exception. How it can pick one particular action method to redirect? Please suggest.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the setup completely. Could you post a bit more about the Controllers and Actions that are defined in you project?

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly , I added some more information hoping that it might be helpful.

Comment: I guess that this is what is happening: ARListing Action method is accessed (by you), but it is not called since ARListingController has the [AllowedToSeeThePage] attribute on it. Instead the OnActionExecuting method of AllowedToSeeThePageAttribute is called first and it redirects you (look within the if) to the AccessDenied action.